# how to load kernel modules on boot?

Tags: yocto

I am new to `yocto` project and I have generated a linux image for my `raspberrypi-cm3`.

I have reconfigured my kernel and added some drivers.
My problem is that all the kernel modules exist on my target under the `/lib/modules` directory but the problem is that each time I need a driver I have to load it manually with the 'insmod' command and sometimes I face some problems because of dependencies.

So I wish someone could tell me how to make my kernel modules loaded automatically on boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD`](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD) is what you're looking for:

```
KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += "module_name1 module_name2 module_name3"
```